# Can MemoryStream reduce its capacity?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, stream, memorystream

When I call MemoryStream.SetLength() and set length less than the current length, is it possible that MemoryStream would reallocate its buffer to reduce the capacity?

In other words, I know that when MemoryStream (created without backing byte[]) is written to, it will dynamically adjust it's capacity reallocating its buffer with twice the size each time the capacity is reached.  My question is, does something like this happen in reverse?  If i reduce the stream length by calling SetLength() would it at some point reallocate to a smaller buffer?  Or would it always keep the same buffer in this case and just change the length variable?

I looked at the source code and it doesn't do it, but since the documentation doesn't exactly spell it out, I m not sure if this could be subject to change.  I m worried if i have a code that often calls SetLength() to reduce the length, could it theoretically incur performance penalty because of internal resizing?

Comment: I think you might just have answered your own question when you said *I looked at the source code and it doesn't do it* but it would be easy to test by writing a huge data to an MS then chopping it, and watching the memory profiler graph in vs?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure though.  The only doc i found says "If the specified value is less than the current length of the stream, the stream is truncated".  From this it is not clear whether truncation involves only setting the length or possible resizing as well.

Comment: Consider also that `MemoryStream` has a `Capacity` property that can be set to a smaller size. That seems to be the way to ask it to resize it's internal array to a smaller size.

Comment: I think it is not possible to set capacity below the current length, otherwise it would thrown an exception.

Comment: Well, I have some code that writes directly to the backing array of the stream (via GetBuffer()).  The problem is that the length of what is to be written is not known until it is actually written.  The only way i found to work with this is to increase the length by the upperbound on that value size and after it is actually written, to reduce the length to be correct (since the size of this data is now known).  This solution seems ok as long as downsizing doesn't happen, hence the question.  I wonder if there is any better way to do this though.

Comment: Actually, yeah, adjusting the capacity up or down will resize the array (as long as capacity >= current length).  Still though, since the doc says that increasing the length may increase the capacity, i wanted to make sure the opposite doesn't happen when the length is decreased.

Comment: *Well, I have some code that writes directly to the backing array of the stream* - what purpose does MemoryStream serve if you bypass it and write to its buffer array directly? Why not just use an array? Would using a set of Span be more useful?

Comment: Unfortunately there are codes that do both, so i do need a stream, plus the upward resizing is needed since the total length is not known in advance.  Yeah the code that deals with the buffer should probably be converted to use stream functions instead.

Comment: Maybe the correct way to deal with this sort of thing for stream that is only used for writing is to use Position to keep track of how much data is in the stream and only use SetLength() for an upper bound (and automatic resizing).  After all the writing is done, the Position will indicate how many bytes total were written.